# Save the powershell's output in a CSV file

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I have a powershell script in which i can get information about my operating system (windows version, build...). However all that information is shown in the powershell console and I want them to be exported to a CSV or a XML file.

The script is :

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem |
    Select-Object  Caption, CSDVersion, ServicePackMajorVersion, BuildNumber |
    FL
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) cmdlet:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Caption, CSDVersion, ServicePackMajorVersion, BuildNumber | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path .\OS_Info.csv
```

Result (`OS_Info.csv`):

```
"Caption","CSDVersion","ServicePackMajorVersion","BuildNumber"
"Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter",,"0","9600"
```

---

> Thank you it worked, the file is generated in the folder `System32`

As Rohin Sidharth mentioned, `.\` prefix for the path will create file in the current dir (`$PWD` in PowerShell). You probably run PowerShell as administrator: in this case the default directory is `%WinDir%\System32`. Just use full path or [GetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath) .Net method to get common folder path, like desktop:

```
... | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\OS_Info.csv'
... | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path (Join-Path -Path [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop') -ChildPath 'OS_Info.csv')
```

> Can you also show me how to export many results in the same file ? for
>   example i have a script in which i can know all the update that are
>   installed :
>
> `Get-Hotfix | Select HotfixID,Description,InstalledOn | Sort InstalledOnfunction`
>
> and i want the results saves in the same CSV file

You can do this by using Select-Object's [calculated properties](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/):

```
# Get OS info
$OsInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem

Get-Hotfix | # Get HotFixes
Sort-Object -Property InstalledOnfunction | # Sort them
Select-Object -Property @( # Select required fields

    # Add Caption property from $OsInfo variable
    @{
        Name = 'Caption'
        Expression = {$OsInfo.Caption}
    }

    # Add CSDVersion property from $OsInfo variable
    @{
        Name = 'CSDVersion'
        Expression = {$OsInfo.CSDVersion}
    }

    # Add ServicePackMajorVersion property from $OsInfo variable
    @{
        Name = 'ServicePackMajorVersion'
        Expression = {$OsInfo.ServicePackMajorVersion}
    }

    # Add BuildNumber property from $OsInfo variable
    @{
        Name = 'BuildNumber'
        Expression = {$OsInfo.BuildNumber}
    }

    # Add other properties from original HotFix object
    'HotfixID'
    'Description'
    'InstalledOn'

) | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\OS_Info.csv'
```

You can also try to [join objects](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/Join-Object) using custom function.

Comment: Thank you it worked, the file is generated in the folder System32.

Comment: Can you show me the way to generate the file in desktop or any other chosen floder ?

Comment: Can you also show me how to export many results in the same file ?
for example i have a script in which i can know all the update that are installed :
Get-Hotfix | Select HotfixID,Description,InstalledOn | Sort InstalledOnfunction 
 and i want the results saves in the same CSV file.

Comment: .\ in front of the filename forces powershell to use the relative path. If your Powershell prompt is at C:\Temp, the file will be created in the temp folder. in your case, it was C:\windows\system32. You can also specify the path ` ... | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\MyScript\OS_Info.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Quick tip:  Make sure you don't pipe to Format List (FL) then pipe to export-csv or you'll open the CSV file and your data will look like this.

```
ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd pageHeaderEntry pageFooterEntry 
autosizeInfo    shapeInfo   groupingEntry
033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280                
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.ListViewHeaderInfo    
9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3                    
27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c                    
4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df                    
cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c
```